# How to disable all ads on webView swift

Tags: swift, webview, uiwebview, adblock, safari-content-blocker

How to disable all ads like popups banner in webView for any URL.

I am using `WKContentRuleListStore` for block ads

I have use this json content block rule
https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/AdsBlock_WKWebView_for_iOS11/blob/master/AdsBlockWKWebView/adaway.json

All block rule assigning to listStore but it's not block all ads. It block some of the ads that mentioned in the json rule want to block all.

```
WKContentRuleListStore.default().lookUpContentRuleList(forIdentifier: ruleId1) { [weak self] (contentRuleList, error) in
}
```

I want to complete block ads on webView. Any help, suggestion appreciate.

Comment: Are you sure the content blocker includes all ads that must be blocked? Have you tried [these lists](https://github.com/brave/adblock-lists)?

Comment: Yes, want to block all ads. How I can use I haven't found any Json file

Comment: It is not possible to completely disable all ads on a UIWebView or WKWebView in iOS using only code. However, you can use third-party libraries or frameworks that allow you to block ads

Comment: can you please suggest to me any good third-party framework? I have checked ABPKit and other libraries but it is not working for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To populate your content-blocking JSON file, you can check out several sources like [EasyList](https://easylist.to/), [Adguard's filters](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardFilters) or [Brave lists](https://github.com/brave/adblock-lists/tree/master) (as suggested by @Mr Developer).

There's also this utility that can help you generate Webkit block lists - [abp2blocklist](https://github.com/adblockplus/abp2blocklist)